# GWC: folder names meaning: why i have folders with the name 'EPSG_3857x2_09' and 'EPSG_3857_09'

Tags: geoserver, tiles, geowebcache, format, directory

- EPSG_3857 is a CRS
- the postfix 09 is a zoom-level
- but why i have folders with structure of:

  - << CRS >>x2_<< zoom-level >>
  - << CRS >>_<< zoom-level >>

Is it a duplicate? What's the meaning of the mysterious 'x2' in the folder name?

Comment: You have set up a grid that is using 512 (or 2x) tiles as well as the normal 256 ones